# Book on real analysis which has more "natural" exercises

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, book-recommendation

Are there any introductory/medium level books on Real Analysis which don't just have a load of pathological examples for the exercises? Most books I've looked at seem to develop the standard material nicely enough (sequences, convergence, functions, continuity, differentiability, integrability) but all the exercises are just "fiddly" little counterexamples or applications to horrible "unnatural" functions. I don't really know how to describe it any better, I'm hoping someone will catch my drift. Surely there is more to analysis than that kind of thing - there must be "natural" examples/exercises...

Answer (score 2):

The pathological examples are more or less provided for the reason that the reader doesn't form a fixed image about some fixed properties. 
Dirichlte's function and Thomae's function are some of the few.

Now, coming to recommendations, "Introduction to Real Analysis, by Bartle" is a great book in my opinion. It's treatment is very neat yet not very hard to follow.

Classics are always there. But for introduction, classics are never good in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Mary Hart's *Guide to Analysis* is a nice introductory book that includes lots of easy exercises. It also contains hints and solutions to many of the exercises.